# Is EF entities creation pluggable?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm looking for something like **IEntitesFactory** or something similar that allows me to handle the Entities instance creation.

Does anybody knows if it's possible with EF 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no extension point to include your own entity factory. You can only handle [ObjectMaterialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx) event for entities loaded from.